# Quickest way to clear all sheet contents VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large sheet that I need to delete all the contents of. When I try to simply clear it without VBA it goes into not responding mode. When using a macro such as:

```
Sub ClearContents ()
 Application.Calculation = XlManual
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Sheets("Zeroes").Cells.ClearContents

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It also doesn't respond. What's the quickest way to do this?

Comment: **Does the sheet contain Conditional Formatting ??**

Comment: Not conditional formatting, no.

Comment: Try `Application.EnableEvents = False: Sheets("Zeroes").Cells.Delete: Application.EnableEvents = True`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The `.Cells` range isn't limited to ones that are being used, so your code is clearing the content of 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns - 17,179,869,184 total cells. That's going to take a while. Just clear the `UsedRange` instead:

```
Sheets("Zeros").UsedRange.ClearContents
```

Alternately, you can delete the sheet and re-add it:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Zeros").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Sheets.Add
sheet.Name = "Zeros"
```

**EDIT:**   (@tavnab and @Azura)
Heads up for future readers, you cannot delete a sheet if it's the last/only one in the workbook.
In that case, you can add the new blank sheet first, delete the old one, and finally rename that new sheet to the old sheet's name.
Also note that eliminating a sheet will create conflicts with formulas in other sheets that were referencing the recently eliminated one, recreating the sheet may not solve that issue.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work either. I've tried doing it out of VBA and just highlighting a snippet (200 rows, 5000 columns) and deleting and that froze it. I've then put a loop in and just tried to loop through 1000 rows, that didn't work either. I may just loop it manually and hold F8 down...

Comment: @hc91 - Interesting.  Sounds like there's enough data that Excel is causing the issue, not VBA.  You can always delete the worksheet and re-add it. See the edit.

Comment: Heads up for future readers, you cannot delete a sheet if it's the last/only one in the workbook. In that case, you can add the new blank sheet first, delete the old one, and finally rename that new sheet to the old sheet's name.

Comment: Also, note that deleting a sheet removes all associated VBA code if this is an issue. I went with just deleting and recreating sheets in a VBA utility I was developing which painted me into a corner when I started adding events to these sheets. My recommendation is `Sheets("Zeroes").Cells.Delete xlShiftUp` which seems instantaneous to me.

Comment: Also note that eliminating a Sheet will create conflicts with formulas in other sheets that were referencing the recently eliminated one, recreating the sheet may not solve that issue.

Comment: If your file is digitally signed: Please also note that the digital signature breaks on insertion and deletion of new worksheets - even if there is no VBA code inside.

Answer (score 12):

Technically, and from Comintern's accepted workaround,
I believe you actually want to Delete all the Cells in the Sheet. Which removes Formatting (See footnote for exceptions), etc. as well as the Cells Contents.
I.e.    `Sheets("Zeroes").Cells.Delete`

Combined also with UsedRange, ScreenUpdating and Calculation skipping it should be nearly intantaneous:

```
Sub DeleteCells ()
    Application.Calculation = XlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Zeroes").UsedRange.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Or if you prefer to respect the Calculation State Excel is currently in:

```
Sub DeleteCells ()
    Dim SaveCalcState
    SaveCalcState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = XlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Zeroes").UsedRange.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = SaveCalcState
End Sub
```

Footnote: If formatting was applied for an *Entire Column*, then it is not deleted.
This includes Font Colour, Fill Colour and Borders, the Format Category (like General, Date, Text, Etc.) and perhaps other properties too, but

Conditional formatting IS deleted, as is *Entire Row* formatting.

(*Entire Column* formatting is quite useful if you are importing raw data repeatedly to a sheet as it will conform to the Formats originally applied if a simple Paste-Values-Only type import is done.)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the .Clear method:

```
Sheets("Zeros").UsedRange.Clear
```

Using this you can remove the **contents** and the **formatting** of a cell or range without affecting the rest of the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Sub clear_sht
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = Worksheets(GENERATOR_SHT_NAME)
  col_cnt = sht.UsedRange.Columns.count
  If col_cnt = 0 Then
    col_cnt = 1
  End If

  sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(sht.UsedRange.Rows.count, col_cnt)).Clear
End Sub
```