# Clearing worksheet speed

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I'm using a macro to clear a worksheet (not delete the worksheet but delete its contents + formatting) and I was wondering what is the fastest alternative to what I'm using. I've used a time recorder on each one.

When I use the code below it does exactly what I need

`Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells.Clear`

but as I'm deleting the contents of many worksheets this makes the macro very slow.

The quickets code is of course:

`Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells.ClearContents`

but this keeps formatting and doesn't seem to delete filtered tables (it keeps the data that was filtered out)

Another alternative is:

`Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp`

but this isn't the quickest option either.

So I wanted to ask which macros work the quickest in deleting contents +  formatting of a worksheet especially when dealing with many different worksheets?

Thanks,

Comment: Try Sheets("Sheet 1").UsedRange.Clear (UsedRange is bound to be a fraction of the size of Cells)

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967411/quickest-way-to-clear-all-sheet-contents-vba)